# Rails4 - How to pass image_tag as a parameter in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to pass image tag as a parameter.

When I try to hardcode it like below, it works perfectly.

**messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController      

  def create
  .
  .
  Pusher['private-'+pushid.id.to_s].trigger('new_message', 
  {:subject => "You have received a new message from <b>John</b>. 
  <img class=\"img-rounded\" 
  src=\"http://mywebsite.com/images/mini/missing.png\"  />" })
  .
  end

end
```

I tried the following to make it dynamic but I get syntax errors. I am not able to pass image tag.

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController      

  def create
  .
  .
  Pusher['private-'+pushid.id.to_s].trigger('new_message', 
  {:subject => "You have received a new message from <b>"+
  current_user.name.capitalize+"</b>." + 
  <%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:mini)).gsub("\"", "'") %>  })
  .
  end

end
```

Could someone share how to do it correctly?
Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: Where is this code located? In an .erb file or a .js file or someplace else?

Comment: @neuronaut Sorry for not providing the file name. Thanks for asking it. I updated the question. I think now I know why it's not working. I am trying to use image_tag in a controller.

Comment: @LovingRails Okay, so the issue is that you don't need to use the `<%` and `%>` delimiters inside of ruby code (and a controller is ruby code). Those delimiters are for .erb files where they mark the beginning and end of ruby inserted into the file. Anyway, the answer from @Exupery should be the way to do it. However, as a rule of thumb its not a good idea to create HTML in your controller -- that's what a view is for.

Comment: Thanks for the info @neuronaut. But the action doesn't have a view. It's executed during post action. This is the route.
messages - POST - /messages(.:format) - messages#create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
subject = "You have received a new message from "+
"<b>#{current_user.name.capitalize}</b>."+
"#{ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:mini)).gsub('"', '\'')}"
Pusher['private-'+pushid.id.to_s].trigger('new_message',{:subject => subject})
```

Within a string you can use `#{RUBY_CODE_HERE}` to insert ruby.

Edit: I pulled the subject out as a variable and made the string multi-line just so it's easier to see within the width of the stackoverflow answer, you can of course keep it as one line in your program.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this is what happens if someone learns rails without learning ruby. I just realized that the code is in controller. So I get image_tag error. After adding ActionController::Base.helpers as prefix to image_tag, it works perfectly. Would you please confirm if it is ok to use #{ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:mini)).gsub("\"", "'")}" ?

Comment: Any valid Ruby code can go in the `#{ }` block so that should work - but you'll need to escape the quotes in gsub (or use single quotes), I'll edit the answer with different quotes.

Comment: I am getting undefined method `image_tag' for #<MessagesController:0x007f044934ca20> if i don't use ActionController::Base.helpers

Comment: @LovingRails Sorry when I updated the answer for the quotes I didn't add `ActionController::Base.helpers` - just edited that in.